# Hibernate fetch strategy

Tags: hibernate

I want to fetch 1 lakh records from a table in multiple Iterations ,I know the solution in normal JDBC pattern by using "fetchSize"  ,but I don't know how to implement in hibernate .  I really appreciate if any one can give me solution for the same .

Comment: what is lakh? Did u realize this is not for only india?

Comment: What is your concern ?"how come nationality comes here" if you didn't understand the question better you can continue your work instead of asking *** questions .

Comment: concern is trying to answer. U got it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setMaxResults` or `setFetchSize` on the session to limit the number of results returned from the DB.